# PostgreSQL SELECT Must Match Across Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.1

I have a table that contains a pair of timestamps that represent a timespan. These rows are scoped by user id, and each user can have one or many rows associated with them.

This data is generated from an abstract "availability" form that represents when the user is available during the week. I need to input a series of time ranges as a query and return all user ids for whom *all rows* in the table match.

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."availability" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "user_id" int4,
  "starts_at" timestamp(6),
  "ends_at" timestamp(6),
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
```

and this data:

```
User #1 is available Mon-Tue between 08:00 and 17:00

+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | starts_at           | ends_at             |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1       | 2013-03-18 08:00:00 | 2013-03-18 17:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 1       | 2013-03-19 08:00:00 | 2013-03-19 17:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

User #2 is available Sun-Sat all day

+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2       | 2013-03-17 00:00:00 | 2013-03-23 23:59:59 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+

User #3 is available Wed between 06:00 and 18:00

+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 3       | 2013-03-20 06:00:00 | 2013-03-20 18:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I can easily select users who are available for *any* of the given timestamps:

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."availability"
  WHERE ('2013-03-19 08:35:00' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at 
     AND '2013-03-19 18:25:00' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at)
    OR  ('2013-03-20 12:00:00' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at
     AND '2013-03-20 18:00:00' BETWEEN starts_at AND ends_at);

+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | starts_at           | ends_at             |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2       | 2013-03-17 00:00:00 | 2013-03-23 23:59:59 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 4  | 3       | 2013-03-20 06:00:00 | 2013-03-20 18:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But what I really need is to be able to query multiple timespans and return only the `user_id`s that match **all** of the conditions.

Query: `2013-03-17 10:00:00`-`2013-03-17 16:00:00`, `2013-03-23 10:00:00`-`2013-03-23 16:00:00` should return:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | starts_at           | ends_at             |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2       | 2013-03-17 00:00:00 | 2013-03-23 23:59:59 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Query: `2013-03-18 09:00:00`-`2013-03-18 16:00:00`, `2013-03-19 08:00:00`-`2013-03-19 15:45:00` should return:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | starts_at           | ends_at             |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1       | 2013-03-18 08:00:00 | 2013-03-18 17:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2  | 1       | 2013-03-19 08:00:00 | 2013-03-19 17:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2       | 2013-03-17 00:00:00 | 2013-03-23 23:59:59 |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Query: `2013-03-18 07:00:00`-`2013-03-18 18:00:00` should return nothing.

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e5724/4/0)

Comment: SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b0fcf/4

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks! I was unaware of SQLfiddle, that is useful.

Comment: Thanks for revising the question. I'll remove my now-irrelevant answer and let others have at it as I'm out of time for now.

Comment: Try using `bool_and` or `bool_or` aggregates from [`this page`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) with grouping by `user_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/e5724/13)

This exploits the boolean cast to integer as 0 or 1.

```
select a.*
from
    availability a
    inner join
    (
        select
            user_id,
            sum (
                ('2013-03-18 09:00:00' between starts_at and ends_at
                 and
                 '2013-03-18 16:00:00' between starts_at and ends_at
                )::integer
                +
                ('2013-03-19 08:00:00' between starts_at and ends_at
                 and
                 '2013-03-19 15:45:00' between starts_at and ends_at
                )::integer
            ) period
        from availability
        group by user_id
    ) s on a.user_id = s.user_id
where period >= 2
```

Change the `where` condition to the number of periods to match.

Answer (score 4):

For an application like this, if you are on PostgreSQL version 9.2 or later, you might want to try a [range type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html).  Here's an example of creating, loading, and displaying the data:

```
CREATE TABLE availability (
  id      int4 NOT NULL,
  user_id int4,
  avail   tstzrange,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO availability VALUES
  (1, 1, '[2013-03-18 08:00:00, 2013-03-18 17:00:00)'),
  (2, 1, '[2013-03-19 08:00:00, 2013-03-19 17:00:00)'),
  (3, 2, '[2013-03-17 00:00:00, 2013-03-23 24:00:00)'),
  (4, 3, '[2013-03-20 06:00:00, 2013-03-20 18:00:00)');
SELECT * FROM availability ;
```

```
 id | user_id |                        avail                        
----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
  1 |       1 | ["2013-03-18 08:00:00-05","2013-03-18 17:00:00-05")
  2 |       1 | ["2013-03-19 08:00:00-05","2013-03-19 17:00:00-05")
  3 |       2 | ["2013-03-17 00:00:00-05","2013-03-24 00:00:00-05")
  4 |       3 | ["2013-03-20 06:00:00-05","2013-03-20 18:00:00-05")
(4 rows)
```

Then you can query with various operators.  If you want all availability ranges that contain *any* of the specified query ranges:

```
SELECT * FROM availability
  WHERE avail @> '[2013-03-19 08:35:00, 2013-03-19 18:25:00)'
     OR avail @> '[2013-03-20 12:00:00, 2013-03-20 18:00:00)';
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM availability
  WHERE avail @> ANY
          (ARRAY ['[2013-03-19 08:35:00, 2013-03-19 18:25:00)'::tstzrange,
                  '[2013-03-20 12:00:00, 2013-03-20 18:00:00)'::tstzrange]);
```

```
 id | user_id |                        avail                        
----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
  3 |       2 | ["2013-03-17 00:00:00-05","2013-03-24 00:00:00-05")
  4 |       3 | ["2013-03-20 06:00:00-05","2013-03-20 18:00:00-05")
(2 rows)
```

If you want all availability ranges that contain *all* of the specified query ranges *in a single range*:

```
SELECT * FROM availability
  WHERE avail @> '[2013-03-17 10:00:00, 2013-03-17 16:00:00)'
    AND avail @> '[2013-03-23 10:00:00, 2013-03-23 16:00:00)';
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM availability
  WHERE avail @> ALL
          (ARRAY ['[2013-03-17 10:00:00, 2013-03-17 16:00:00)'::tstzrange,
                  '[2013-03-23 10:00:00, 2013-03-23 16:00:00)'::tstzrange]);
```

```
 id | user_id |                        avail                        
----+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
  3 |       2 | ["2013-03-17 00:00:00-05","2013-03-24 00:00:00-05")
(1 row)
```

If you want all availability ranges that contain *any* of the specified query ranges, **but only for users with availability ranges which cover *all* of the specified query ranges**:

```
WITH s(ts) AS
(
  VALUES
    ('[2013-03-18 09:00:00, 2013-03-18 16:00:00)'::tstzrange),
    ('[2013-03-19 08:00:00, 2013-03-19 15:45:00)'::tstzrange)
)
SELECT DISTINCT a1.*
  FROM s s1
  JOIN availability a1 ON a1.avail @> s1.ts
    AND NOT EXISTS
        (
          SELECT * FROM s s2
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (
                    SELECT * FROM availability a2
                      WHERE a2.user_id = a1.user_id
                        AND a2.avail @> s2.ts
                  )
        );
```

or (adapting Clodoaldo Neto's query to use ranges):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM availability a
  JOIN (
         SELECT
             user_id,
             sum(('[2013-03-18 09:00:00, 2013-03-18 16:00:00)'::tstzrange
                   <@ avail)::integer
                 +
                 ('[2013-03-19 08:00:00, 2013-03-19 15:45:00)'::tstzrange
                   <@ avail)::integer
                ) period
           FROM availability
           GROUP BY user_id
       ) s ON a.user_id = s.user_id
  WHERE period >= 2;
```

You can create an index to make such searches very fast on large tables like this:

```
CREATE INDEX availability_avail ON availability USING gist (avail);
```

Notes:

- I left off the schema and quotes for readability.
- The index is unlikely to be used with four rows, because all the data will be available more quickly by directly reading the one data page.  With large tables it could make a big difference.
- I used ranges of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` because with the default (bare) `TIMESTAMP` the clock moves backward each year at the end of Daylight Saving Time.  To capture moments in time, use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` (`timestamptz` for short).
- When used directly, the literals need not be explicitly cast; when using the `ANY` or `ALL` form of the query, explicit casts are needed.
- Square brackets on a range mean that the range *includes* the adjacent time, while rounded parentheses mean that the range *excludes* the adjacent time.  Timestamps are generally specified using `[)` so that a range ending with a given time and another range starting with the same time are considered *adjacent* rather than *overlapping*.
- `'24:00:00'` for one date and `'00:00:00'` for the next date are the same moment.
- The two preceding points allow easier specification of a timestamp ending at midnight.  There is no risk of a "lost second" or other strangeness.

Comment: This is probably the _more correct_ answer, as the range datatype is obviously well-suited to this problem. We are in the process of working on an upgrade to 9.2, so this is probably the approach I will end up with.